# I(A) is the set of all isolated points of A

Tags: analysis

I(A) is the set of all isolated points of A

(isolated point means point $x$ such that $x \in A$ but $x$ is not a limit point of A)

${S_k}$ is a sequnce such that For all $k\in N$, $I(S_k)=\varnothing$

$S=\cap S_k$

Then $I(S)=\varnothing$?

I couldn't find a counterexample, so is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(\Bbb{R}, \tau_{euclidean}) $

Choose, $S_k=(-\frac{1}{k}, {\frac{1}{k}}) \subset \Bbb{R}$

Prove :

1. $I(S_k) =\emptyset$
2. $S= \cap_{k\in\Bbb{N}} S_k =\{0\}$

(Hint : Use Archimedean property of real)

3. $I(S) =\{0\}$

Done. Let's try to find different examples , probably different topological spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

When looking for a counterexample here, choose an $S$ first, preferably as simple as possible, with $I(S)\neq\varnothing$. Then build a suitable sequence $S_k$.